# Adding in drops from enemies in Pygame?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I am trying to add in random drops from enemy deaths to a game I am making in Python and wondering how to implement it. the drops I am wanting to add currently are shield and health, with shield having a lower drop chance. The main code for Drops are here:

```
import pygame

class HealthDrop(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

        def __init__(self, x, y):

                self.image = pygame.image.load('images/Sprites/health.png')

                self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
                self.rect.x = x
                self.rect.y = y

                self.on_ground = False
                self.gravity = 0.5

        def update(self):


        def render(self, surface):
                surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)

class ShieldDrop(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

        def __init__(self, x, y):

                self.image = pygame.image.load('images/Sprites/shield.png')

                self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
                self.rect.x = x
                self.rect.y = y

                self.on_ground = False
                self.gravity = 0.5

        def update(self):


        def render(self, surface):
                surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

Then the code for the main file is here:

```
import pygame, sys
import random
import pygame.mixer
import Funk
from time import sleep
from player import *
from zombie import *
from level import *
from bullet import *
from constants import *
from Drops import *
import menu as dm

class Game():

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        pygame.mixer.init()

        #pygame.mixer.music.load('sounds/menugame.ogg')
        #pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

        # A few variables
        self.gravity = .50
        self.ground = pygame.Rect(0, 640, 1280, 80)
        self.red = (255, 0, 0)
        self.darkred = (200, 0, 0)
        self.darkblue = (0, 0, 200)
        self.darkgreen = (0, 200, 0)
        self.gameover = pygame.image.load('images/gameover.png')
        self.victory = pygame.image.load('images/victory.png')

        # Bullets
        self.bullets = []

        # Screen
        size = (1280, 720)
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
        pygame.display.set_caption('Moon Survival!')

        # Moon / Background
        self.moon = Background()
        self.text1 = pygame.image.load('images/TextSlides/Text1.jpg')
        self.text2 = pygame.image.load('images/TextSlides/Text2.jpg')

        # Zombies
        self.zombies = []
        for i in range(15):
            self.zombies.append( Zombie(random.randint(0,1280), random.randint(0,720)) )

        self.zombieskilled = 0

        # Player
        self.player = Player(25, 320, self.gravity)

        # Font for text
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 72)

        # game over
        self.gameover_text = self.font.render("The Aliens Are Too Good", -1, (255, 0, 0))
        self.gameover_rect = self.gameover_text.get_rect(center=self.screen.get_rect().center)

        # game state
        self.game_state = STATE_INGAME

    def run(self):

        clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        # "state machine" 
        RUNNING   = True
        PAUSED    = False 
        GAME_OVER = False

        # Game loop
        while RUNNING:

            # (all) Events
            if self.game_state == STATE_INGAME:

                for event in pygame.event.get():

                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        RUNNING = False

                    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

                        if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                            self.bullets.append(Bullet(self.player.rect.x + 30, self.player.rect.y + 30, self.player.direction))

                        if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                            RUNNING = False

                        elif event.key == pygame.K_p:
                            # set state to paused
                            self.game_state = STATE_PAUSED

                    # Player/Zomies events  
                    self.player.handle_events(event)

                # (all) Movements / Updates

                self.player_move()
                self.player.update()

                for z in self.zombies:
                    self.zombie_move(z)       
                    z.update(self.screen.get_rect())

                for b in self.bullets:
                    b.update()
                    for tile in self.moon.get_surrounding_blocks(b):
                        if tile is not None:
                            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(b, tile):
                                # Destroy block
                                x = tile.rect.x / tile.rect.width
                                y = tile.rect.y / tile.rect.height
                                self.moon.levelStructure[x][y] = None
                                self.bullets.remove(b)

                # (all) Display updating

                self.moon.render(self.screen)

                for z in self.zombies:
                    z.render(self.screen)

                for b in self.bullets:
                    b.render(self.screen)

                self.player.render(self.screen)

                Funk.text_to_screen(self.screen, 'Level 1', 5, 675)
                Funk.text_to_screen(self.screen, 'Health: {0}'.format(self.player.health), 5, 0)
                Funk.text_to_screen(self.screen, 'Score: {0}'.format(self.player.score), 400, 0)
                Funk.text_to_screen(self.screen, 'Time: {0}'.format(self.player.alivetime), 750, 0)
                Funk.text_to_screen(self.screen, 'Kills: {0}'.format(self.zombieskilled), 5, 50)
                Funk.text_to_screen(self.screen, 'Lives: {0}'.format(self.player.lives), 300, 50)

            elif self.game_state == STATE_PAUSED:
                # (all) Display updating

                if self.game_state == STATE_INGAME:
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        RUNNING = False

                    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                        if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                            RUNNING = False

                choose = dm.dumbmenu(self.screen, [
                            'Resume Game',

                            'Menu',

                            'Quit Game'], 200, 200,'orecrusherexpanded',100,0.75,self.darkred,self.red)

                if choose == 0:
                    print "You choose 'Start Game'."
                    # set state to ingame
                    self.game_state = STATE_INGAME
                elif choose == 1:
                    print "You choose 'Controls'."
                if choose == 2:
                    print "You choose 'Quit Game'."
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

                #for event in pygame.event.get():


                self.moon.render(self.screen)

                for z in self.zombies:
                    z.render(self.screen)

                for b in self.bullets:
                    b.render(self.screen)

                self.player.render(self.screen)

                Funk.text_to_screen(self.screen, 'Level 1', 5, 675)
                Funk.text_to_screen(self.screen, 'Health: {0}'.format(self.player.health), 5, 0)
                Funk.text_to_screen(self.screen, 'Score: {0}'.format(self.player.score), 400, 0)
                Funk.text_to_screen(self.screen, 'Time: {0}'.format(self.player.alivetime), 750, 0)
                Funk.text_to_screen(self.screen, 'Kills: {0}'.format(self.zombieskilled), 850, 0)

            elif self.game_state == STATE_GAMEOVER:
                self.screen.blit(self.gameover, (0, 0))
                pygame.display.update()
                choose = dm.dumbmenu(self.screen, [
                            'New Game',
                            '  Menu  ',
                            'Quit Game'], 200, 300,'orecrusherexpanded',100,0.75,self.darkred,self.red)

                if choose == 0:
                    print "You choose 'Start Game'."
                    # set state to ingame
                    self.game_state = STATE_INGAME

                    execfile('MoonSurvival.py')
                if choose == 1:
                    print "You choose 'Start Game'."
                    execfile('run_game.py')

                if choose == 2:
                    print "You choose 'Start Game'."
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

            pygame.display.update()

            # FTP

            clock.tick(100)

        # --- the end ---
        pygame.quit()

    def player_move(self):
        # add gravity
        self.player.do_jump()

        # simulate gravity
        self.player.on_ground = False
        if not self.player.on_ground and not self.player.jumping:
            self.player.velY = 4

        # Health
        for zombie in self.zombies:
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self.player, zombie):
                self.player.health -= 5

                # check if we die
                if self.player.health <= 0:
                    self.player.lives -= 1
                    self.player.rect.x = 320
                    self.player.rect.y = 320
                    self.player.health += 200
                if self.player.lives <= 0:
                    sleep(2)
                    self.game_state = STATE_GAMEOVER

        # move player and check for collision at the same time
        self.player.rect.x += self.player.velX
        self.check_collision(self.player, self.player.velX, 0)
        self.player.rect.y += self.player.velY
        self.check_collision(self.player, 0, self.player.velY)

    def zombie_move(self, zombie_sprite):
        # add gravity
        zombie_sprite.do_jump()

        # simualte gravity
        zombie_sprite.on_ground = False
        if not zombie_sprite.on_ground and not zombie_sprite.jumping:
            zombie_sprite.velY = 4

        # Zombie damage
        for zombie in self.zombies:
            for b in self.bullets:
                if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(b, zombie):
                    #The same bullet cannot be used to kill
                    #multiple zombies and as the bullet was 
                    #no longer in Bullet.List error was raised
                    zombie.health -= 10                
                    self.bullets.remove(b)
                    if zombie.health <= 0:
                        self.zombieskilled += 1
                        self.player.score += 20
                        self.zombies.remove(zombie)
                    break

        # move zombie and check for collision
        zombie_sprite.rect.x += zombie_sprite.velX
        self.check_collision(zombie_sprite, zombie_sprite.velX, 0)
        zombie_sprite.rect.y += zombie_sprite.velY
        self.check_collision(zombie_sprite, 0, zombie_sprite.velY)

    def check_collision(self, sprite, x_vel, y_vel):
        # for every tile in Background.levelStructure, check for collision
        for block in self.moon.get_surrounding_blocks(sprite):
            if block is not None:
                if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(sprite, block):
                    # we've collided! now we must move the collided sprite a step back
                    if x_vel < 0:
                        sprite.rect.x = block.rect.x + block.rect.w

                        if type(sprite) is Zombie:
                            # the sprite is a zombie, let's make it jump
                            if not sprite.jumping:
                                sprite.jumping = True
                                sprite.on_ground = False

                    if x_vel > 0:
                        sprite.rect.x = block.rect.x - sprite.rect.w

                        if type(sprite) is Zombie:
                            # the sprite is a zombie, let's make it jump
                            if not sprite.jumping:
                                sprite.jumping = True
                                sprite.on_ground = False

                    if y_vel < 0:
                        sprite.rect.y = block.rect.y + block.rect.h

                    if y_vel > 0 and not sprite.on_ground:
                        sprite.on_ground = True
                        sprite.rect.y = block.rect.y - sprite.rect.h

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

Game().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to edit this:

```
def zombie_move(self, zombie_sprite):
    for zombie in self.zombies:
        for b in self.bullets:
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(b, zombie):
                zombie.health -= 10                
                self.bullets.remove(b)
                if zombie.health <= 0:
                    self.zombieskilled += 1
                    self.player.score += 20

                    #You need some code here (before removing the zombie)

                    self.zombies.remove(zombie)
                break
```

I'm sorry I forgot how to do it in Python, but the logic is like that: In place of the comment inside the code add something like `HealthDrop.append(x, y)` or `ShieldDrop.append(x, y)` where x and y should be zombie's values (that's why you should do it before removing the zombie).

If you want random chance just add `import random` then do it like that:

```
percentage = random.randint(1, 100)

if (percentage >= 1) and (percentage < 10)
    healthDrop.append(zombie.x, zombie.y)
else
if (percentage >= 10) and (percentage < 20)
    shieldDrop.append(zombie.x, zombie.y)
```

In this example I set 10% for each "item" to drop (they can't both drop), it randomizes a number from 1 to 100 , if it's a number from 1 to 9 its healthDrop, if it's a number from 10 to 19 its shieldDrop, feel free to experiment with what percentages makes your game balanced

Also don't forget to add collision (I see you already have some code for collision so I guess you know how to do it). The rest of the code should be easy for you to do (like increasing health on pick up etc etc.

I'm sorry I don't remember python really well, but you can use them similar to the bullet class, I hope you have the idea, if there's anything troubling you please tell me and I'll help more :)

Comment: Ok will try that and see how it goes. Will get back if anything is wrong. I am currently getting errors about shieldDrop and healthDrop not being defined.

Comment: sure, if you get stuck at any moment let me know ! :D

Comment: Thats the only real error I get with the shieldDrop and healthDrop not being defined and not sure how to define them :(

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, can't you just copy what you did with zombies and/or bullets? and then change when they are called

Comment: I will try that later as for now I need some rest.  Will tell you how it goes when I try. Thank you